# cfapplication variable & error

Tags: coldfusion

I have just started ColdFusion development and am getting stuck at creating a `cfapplication` that stores a variable, to use at a later date. All the tutor has provided us with is the following:

> "Create your own 'Application.cfm' and save it in the root folder
>   alongside your 'hello world' examples."

i have this so far

```
<CFAPPLICATION 
    name=“mySite” 
    sessionmanagement=“yes” 
    clientmanagement=“yes”
    setclientcookies=“yes”>
```

I want to add in a variable message that says "hello world". But I have no idea how to do it. I have been searching the net, but can't find any help. I am also getting the following message but have found no help on to resolve it:

> "The value of the SESSIONMANAGEMENT attribute is invalid. The value
>   cannot be converted to a boolean because it is not a simple
>   value.Simple values are booleans, numbers, strings, and date-time
>   values."

If someone could help me with these that would be great, or if you can perhaps point me in the direction of some good ColdFusion tutorials that would be even better. As sadly there doesn't seam to be many decent ColdFusion tutorial's around that explain what's going on. Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: The sessionmanagement error is because you've got `“...”` instead of `"..."` - delete the quotes and re-type them with a keyboard.

Comment: For general learning, there's a tutorial series at [**learncfinaweek.com**](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/) that should cover the basics.

Comment: Ah the quotes that have caused many a `“smart”` person to feel very "stupid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to set your variable is:

```
 <cfset application.message = "Hello World">
```

Your error might be caused by the curly quotes in your code.